# Replace a comma in between two double quotes

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I would like to replace a comma in between two double quotes.

### EXAMPLE:

Replace:

```
11/18/2015,15:27,1,103,3,,,197179,"Petco, Inc.",Amy,Jr,187.061,452.5,0,0,0,2.419,0,0,37.38,489.88`
```

With:

```
11/18/2015,15:27,1,103,3,,,197179,"Petco Inc.",Amy,Jr,187.061,452.5,0,0,0,2.419,0,0,37.38,489.88
```

**NOTE: I still want to keep the bare commas I just want to replace any commas that are inside of the double quote "**

I know I can replace the commas by doing this:  `strText = Replace(strText, ",", "")`

but how do I do that in between the two double quotes only and not affect the other commas that are outside of the double quotes.

Tried this thanks to pee2pee but getting an error: Expected identifier

```
.Pattern    = "/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g"
-------------------^


  dim re
  Set re = New RegExp
  With re
      .Pattern    = "/(""".*?"""|[^""",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g"
      .IgnoreCase = False
      .Global     = False
  End With
  Set re = Nothing
```

Thanks

Comment: Nothing makes sense here. Not the question, not the tag not the code fragment. You should start from scratch, maybe go through [ask] first

Comment: add the [regex] tag, that might help to get an answer.

Comment: @Amit what is so hard to understand ? I want to remove a comma that is in between the two double quotes.

Comment: fixed the tag..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Classic one:

```vb
csv = "..." ' your lines
ReDim chars(Len(csv) - 1) 'array for output
wearein = False
For i = 1 To Len(csv)
    chars(i-1) = Mid(csv, i, 1)
    Select Case chars(i-1)
        Case Chr(34) 'we're in
            wearein = Not wearein
        Case ","
            If wearein Then chars(i-1) = ""
    End Select
Next
newstr = Join(chars, "")
Response.Write newstr
```

2 - By using RegExp and a callback function :

```vb
Function ReplaceCallback(match, position, all)
    ReplaceCallback = Replace(match, ",", "")
End Function

Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = """[^""]*,[^""]*"""
    re.Global = True

csv = "..." 'your lines
newstr = re.Replace(csv, GetRef("ReplaceCallback")) 'replace done
Response.Write newstr
```

3 - By mixing MS JScript and VBScript:

```vb
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
function removeCommas(text){
    return text.replace(/"[^"]*,[^"]*"/g, function(){return arguments[0].replace(/,/g, "")});
}
</script>
<%
csv = "..." 'your lines
Response.Write removeCommas(csv)
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex  pattern you need would be something like

```
/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I think this will work, as I have tested it on regexr.com but how do I add this into asp(classic).. I updated the code so you can see how I tried but I get an error. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

ONLY and **ONLY** in this case, you can use:

```
strText = Replace(strText, ", ", " ")
```

because you have just a space after the comma you need to replace.

Comment: With this function, you'll replace all the commas, followed by a single space. That'a all ;)

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at it wrong. I need to replace only the comma inside the double quotes... For example: 197179,"Petco, Inc.",Amy,Jr,187.061 it should be 197179,"Petco Inc.",Amy,Jr,187.061

Comment: I still want to keep the comma's I just want to replace any comma's that are inside of the double quotes "

Answer (score 0):

An easy (but probably not that efficient) solution could be going one char at a time changing the comma if you passed an uneven amount of double quotes, finishing after the last double quote.

```
string origin = ""; //Your string to convert
int lastIndex = origin.LastIndexOf('"');
bool betweenQuotes = false;

for(int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
{
  if(origin[i] == '"')
    betweenQuotes = !betweenQuotes;

  if(origin[i] == ',' && betweenQuotes)
    origin[i] = ' ';
}
```

Edit: You can't set a char like I did in the last row

```
origin[i] = ' ';
```

it won't work in c#.
put in that line this instead

```
origin = origin.Substring(0, i) + " " + origin.Substring(i + 1);
```

That solution was for C#, so I made a code in VB that does the same thing since as I understood online ASP works (or at least can work) with VB. (Sorry, but it's my first time working with classic asp and VB). But this code in VB is working for me.

```
Dim origin As String = "11/18/2015,15:27,1,103,3,,,197179,fPetco, Inc.f,Amy,Jr,187.061,452.5,0,0,0,2.419,0,0,37.38,489.88"
Dim lastIndex As Integer = 0
Dim betweenQuotes As Boolean = False


For i As Integer = 0 To origin.Length - 1
    If origin(i) = "f" Then
        lastIndex = i
    End If
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To lastIndex
    If origin(i) = "f" Then
        betweenQuotes = Not betweenQuotes
    End If

    If origin(i) = "," AndAlso betweenQuotes Then
        origin = origin.Substring(0, i) + " " + origin.Substring(i + 1)
    End If
Next
```

I just replaced the double quotes with the f char since I have no idea how to put special chars in a string in VB. but this code replaces the comma only between the Fs, so it should be ok.

I also made a JS version, cause that would work everywhere on the web doesn't matter what language you used to create the page.

```
var origin = "";
         var lastIndex = 0;
         var betweenQuotes = false;

         for (var i = 0; i < origin.length ; i++)
             if (origin[i] == '"')
                 lastIndex = i;

         for(i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++)
         {
             if (origin[i] == '"')
                 betweenQuotes = !betweenQuotes;

             if (origin[i] == ',' && betweenQuotes) {
                 origin = origin.substr(0, i) + " " + origin.substr(i + 1, origin.length - i - 1);
             }
         }
```

Comment: oh wow I missed the asp part. >.< sry about that. let me see what I can do in asp

Comment: @compcobalt added 2 codes one in VB and one in JS, which rely on the same logic as the initial solution. Hope they are more useful ^.^